# Обособление вопросов

Tags: пунктуация, вопрос

Допустим, даны предложения:

> Когда и как мы будем решать проблему и будем ли?

> Как и зачем мы придем к решению этой проблемы и когда?

Они правильно оформлены? Разве нельзя их оформить таким образом, без расчленения на предложения? Какого правила можно придерживаться при обособлении подобных предложений?

Comment: Что значит без расчленения на предложения?

Comment: "Когда мы будем решать проблему? Как? Будем ли?",

                              "Как и зачем мы придем к решению этой проблемы? Когда?"

Answer (score 1):

Если ***и будем ли***, ***и когда*** — члены предложения, то ничего ставить не нужно. Но если эти же слова — присоединения, которые хотел добавить автор, то надо поставить запятые:

***Когда и как мы будем решать проблему, и будем ли?***;

***Как и зачем мы придем к решению этой проблемы, и когда?***

Здесь даже **паузы есть**, так что, на мой взгляд, **лучше эти запятые поставить**.